# Correct method signature for RichGroupReduceFunction?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

The below extended class of [RichGroupReduceFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/RichGroupReduceFunction.html), does not compile. The signature seemingly does not match the interface. I can't tell the difference.

```
   class SPointReduce extends RichGroupReduceFunction[Int, Int] {
      override def reduce (
                                 values: Iterable[Int],
                                 out: Collector[Int]): Unit = {
        values.foreach {
          value: Int =>
            out.collect(value)
        }
      }
    }
```

The compiler reports:

> Error:(62, 16) method reduce overrides nothing.
>   Note: the super classes of class SPointReduce contain the
>   following, non final members named reduce: def reduce(x$1:
>   Iterable[Nothing],x$2: org.apache.flink.util.Collector[Nothing]): Unit
>   override def reduce (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that you import the `java.lang.Iterable` when you override the `reduce` method of `RichGroupReduceFunction`. Otherwise, you will get the above mentioned error.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.